# How to use Scipy's Kd-tree function to speed up K-Nearest Neighbors (KNN)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm looking to use [Scipy's Kd-tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) to speed up a KNN search, but it is unclear to me how to format the data to 1)- create the tree and 2) - use the tree to speed up my search.

To elaborate, I have a pandas dataframe of Netflix training data that is composed of columns of users, each movie item they have rated, and the rating they have given it (see below). Using this training data, I'm now predict a rating for a test user by calculating the the nearest neighbor (KNN) to the test user. The nearest neighbor is calculated using a Pearson's correlation coefficient, not euclidean distance. Once the nearest neighbor is calculated, I would like predict/guess the rating for the test user using the nearest neighbor.

However, my list of users and movies is large (netflix data) and calculating the nearest neighbor for thousands of users across thousands of movies becomes computationally infeasible. The Kd-tree approach has been suggested as way to speed K nearest neighbor.

Is there a way to speed this approach using Scipy's Kd-tree? If so, what format does the data need to be in to utilize the Kd-tree approach? I know there is a built in Ski-kit learn function for this exact question, but I need to be able to implement this independently.

```
Goal: predict user 1 rating on movie 10 by finding most similar users 

Training data
user    movie   rating
2         7      5.0
3        10      3.0
4         4      1.0
50     3363      2.0
50       7       3.0
83      50       4.0
83       7       5.0
etc
```

Comment: Why is scipy allowed, but not sklearn? Scipy's kdtree, as far as i know, only support p-norm metrics, so there is nothing you can do! kNN is known to not scale very well for this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scipy's KD Tree only supports p-norm metrics (e.g. p=2 is the standard Euclidean distance). If you want more general metrics, scikit-learn's [BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) supports a number of different metrics. In particular, the [correlation metric](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.correlation.html) is related to the Pearson correlation coefficient, so you could base your algorithm on an efficient search with this metric.

That said, if you have thousands of dimensions, a tree-based approach is often not all that better than brute force. Better is to use some sort of approximate algorithm, such as Locality Sensitive Hashing, with a hash function designed for the correlation distance.

Comment: Are you aware of an easy to implement locality sensitive hashing algorithm that could be used for this, preferably already implemented in a python package?